# Angularjs select with group based on two tables

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have two arrays that stripped down looks like this:

USERS (username, companyid) and
COMPANIES (companyid, companyname)

I want to fill a select with users, grouped by company names, hopefully without having to add companyname directly to users.

This works, but then I get the companyid instead of company name:

```
 ng-options="user as username group by user.companyid for user in users"
```

I want to join the second table so that I can get the company name. Is a query like this possible?

```
ng-options="user as username group by company.Company for user in users inner join company in companies"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out the wanted solution for this, so I will still be grateful for answers.

However, I added a function to help out, so that at least the problem is solved, even if not quite how I like it solved. Using grep in jquery for finding the corresponding company.

In markup:

```
ng-options="user as user.name group by getCompanyName(user.companyid) for user in users"
```

In Control:

```
$scope.getCompanyName = function (compId) {
        var compName = $.grep($scope.companies, function (company) { return company.companyid=== compId });
        return compName[0].Name;
    }
```